# Parse XMLHTTP responseText (HTML) in Jscript ES3 in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, jscript, ecmascript-3

for reasons I won't bore you with, I am using a scriptcontrol JScript object in VBA to retrieve a webpage.
I do this as follows (in 32bit Excel, for 64bit I use a MSHTA work-around).

```
Sub Test()
Dim S as Object
    Set S = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
        S.Language = "JScript"

        S.Eval("var x = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');")
        S.Eval("x.open('GET', 'https://stackoverflow.com/', false);")
        S.Eval("x.Send")
End Sub
```

Now this works fine and the returning response is in x.ResponseText, but how can I parse this in a HTML Document from which I can get specific document elements?
JScript = ES3 and doesn't have DOMParser, jquery or the standard document.whatever.

I added John Resig's pure javascript HTML parser from https://johnresig.com/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/ and while I can add the code (S.Addcode), it errors on me when using HTMLToDom;

```
S.AddCode JohnsCode
S.Eval ("var d = new ActiveXObject('HTMLFile');")
S.Eval ("HTMLToDom(x.ResponseText, d);") <-- this errors.
```

Am I missing something obvious here or is parsing a HTML response into a HTML Document where I can retrieve specific elements not possible in JScript/ES3?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well..I am still gonna say it, why can't this be done with a standard xmlhttp request please?

Comment: `d.write(x.ResponseText);`

Comment: @QHarr jscript is quicker in parsing, xmlhttp in jscript has an async onreadystatechange option, string modification is easier in jscript - AND I just want to know how it's done :)

Comment: Fair play then  :-)

Comment: @omegastripes - that works for stackoverflow.com, but not for some more complex sites, that DO render in a CreateObject("HTMLFile") in VBA. Anything I can do about that or 'tough luck'?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of such more complex site?